Need reliable release mechanism in tight space where activation is hitting a pin on the bottom of the shaft and the lock released is on top of shaft
(see screenshots for more detail)
I'm an ME AE and I have this project for my kid.
I have a tight space of only 5mm x 5mm x 81mm cut into the side of a shaft. The mechanism activates a release by having a pin hit something on the bottom of the shaft, which releases the lock at the top of the shaft. This allows the projectile sliding on the shaft to release and launch in a specific controlled direction.
I've tried multiple solutions which have failed.
I tried using a 1mm x 3mm x 81mm carbon fiber flat rod, held at the bottom of cut area. It's elasticity should have worked but it seems that the  polymer of the shaft degraded and couldn't hold the top end up.
I tried a spring array with a flat surface of 1mm x 4mm x 81mm in the channel but it was too complicated to assemble and reliability was lacking. Not to mention my limited space in the channel on the side of the shaft was reduced greatly by having to implement the spring mechanism.
I tried a 2mm thick spring steel rod with a screwed down base by it didn't seem to lower and rise enough when the pin hit.
Any other suggestions?
See screenshots for more details.





is the blue projectile launched one time only?
